# python argument parser defines variable name for list type input

Tags: python, argparse

I have an option to read a list of input from users. The list can have a random length. Here is my code:

```
parser.add_argument('-at', '--addTests', metavar=('test_commands'), nargs='+')
```

using 'metavar' is a good way to give names to variables but it does not work good when nargs is not fixed.

The result I get from this line is :

```
-at test_command [test_command ...], --addTests test_command [test_command]
```

I hope the result only have "test_command" displays one time.

Comment: This is expected behaviour. If you want multiple `metavar`s to display inside `[ ]`, then you need to use `parser.add_argument('-at', '--addTests', metavar=('test_command', 'test_command2'), nargs='+')`

Comment: @ResetACK That is not what I want. Users are supposed to give any number of input and parser regards them as ONE list variable

Comment: metavars are just placeholders, they don't get stored by the argument parser. If you use what I gave you and provide a list of commands separated by space, it will give you the output you're looking for. See my answer for details.

Comment: I just realised where you're getting confused: you're thinking that `--addTests test_command [test_command]` means that `[test_command]` is a list of arguments. `[arg]` notation is used for arguments that are optional. Since you have used `nargs='+'`, users must provide ***at least*** one argument for the `-at/--addTests` option, and any further arguments are optional for `--addTests`

Comment: Thus, using `--addTests test_command test_command2` when invoking your script, `args = parser.parse_args()` will give the following parsed args: `Namespace(addTests=['test_command', 'test_command2']`. Then you can access them by using `for command in args.addTests: print command` (or instead of printing you can run them, etc.

Comment: @ResetACK Oh right! You hit the point! So the problem get solved. Do you mind to edit your answer again and I accept it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting confused with the meaning of

```
--addTests test_command [test_command]
```

You think it means that `[test_command]` is a list of arguments.

Note that `[arg]` notation is used for arguments that are optional. Since you have used `nargs='+'`, users must provide ***at least*** one argument for the `-at/--addTests` option, and any further arguments are optional for `--addTests`.

Thus, using:

```
--addTests test_command test_command2
```

when invoking your script:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

will give the following parsed args:

```
Namespace(addTests=['test_command', 'test_command2']
```

Then you can access them by using:

```
for command in args.addTests: 
    print command
```

Alternatively (instead of printing) you can run the commands, etc.

Comment: Appreciate that!